# Pluralization bug in days visited

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, plurals, visited-days

Currently there's a pluralization bug in the profile page with *"Visited N day"* phrased in the singular.

[image: The top of a Stack Exchange profile page, with the text "Visited 613 day" underlined]

Comment: Mandatory comment about something deprecated with something deprecated

Comment: Deprecated mandatory comment chastising Oleg for posting something deprecated.

Comment: @Oleg Valter: Something related to [giants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standing_on_the_shoulders_of_giants#Isaac_Newton) but without shoulders?

Comment: @P.Mort.-forgotClayShirky_q ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Fixed

> <sigh>; one days; three day
> once more, pluralization
> rears its ugly head